# passar valor de input para variável de sessão php sem reload da página

Tags: php, html

Boas.

Qual a melhor forma de passar um valor de input para uma variável de sessão em php sem o reload da página?

Por exemplo, com este método a página faz o reload:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="valor1" onchange="submit()">
</form>

<?php
session_start();

if($_POST['valor1']){
   $_SESSION['valor1'] = $_POST['valor1'];
}
?>
```

De que forma posso obter o mesmo resultado sem o reload?

Comment: Com JQuery + AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando carregamento assíncrono, com a utilização do Ajax.

Exemplo com jQuery:

**Página form.php**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="valor1" id="valor1">
      </form>
    </form>
    
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $("#valor1").change( function(){
      
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "salvarNaSessao.php",
        data: 'valor' + $("#valor1").val()
      }).done(function() {
        alert('dados enviados');
      });
      
    });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Página salvarNaSessao.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['valor1'])){
   $_SESSION['valor1'] = $_POST['valor1'];
}
?>
```

Comment: seguindo este exemplo, não consegui o resultado na variável de sessão php. ele adiciona uma variável (valor1) na url, ex.: ?valor1=677666.

Comment: Faltou `type: "POST"` na resposta por isso está enviando `GET`

Comment: @Groot Corrigi o código....